# C# - send class type as parameter in methods and create constructor in them

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, oop, dry, typeof

How I can *DRY* this cases, the only diffrence of them are Type of **commandData** and **command**?

```c#
switch (opCode)
   {
       case OpCode.SetupGame:
       SetupGameData commandData1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SetupGameData>(message);
       SetupGame command1 = new SetupGame(gameModel, commandData1);
       command1.RegisterOnComplete(StartGame);
       gameModel.commandManager.AddCommand(command1);
       break;
       case OpCode.StartGame:
       StartGameData commandData2 =JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<StartGameData>(message);
       StartGame command2 = new StartGame(gameModel, commandData2);
       command2.RegisterOnComplete(StartGame);
       gameModel.commandManager.AddCommand(command2);
       break;
   }
```

How can I create a method and only pass type of these classes, something like this?

```c#
CreateLocalCommand(typeof(SetupGameData), typeof(SetupGame))
```

*Update* :

**SetupGameData** and **StartGameData** are childs of *CommandData*

**SetupGame** and **StartGame** are childs of *BasicCommand*, each command has its own commandData type

Comment: Could you add a little more context? e.g. what are `SetupGame` and `StartGame`? Do they have a common base type? Do your "data" types have a common base type? You could probably use a [generic](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/types/generics) and pass in both types as generic type parameters

Comment: updated, I can't use parent class because  they are abstract

Comment: Please include an [mcve] that we could actually run in a Console or https://dotnetfiddle.net/.

Answer (score 2):

#### Generics

You probably want to use [generics](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/types/generics).

I don't have all your types but you could probably do something like this

- First of all in order to create instances of generics you need a parameter-less constructor and then a method to actually initialize the fields. (See also [`new` type constraint](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/new-constraint))
- I would strongly couple each command to its according data type by e.g. making it

  ```
  public abstract class BasicCommand<TData> where TData : CommandData 
  {
      ... 
  }
  ```

So you would have something like e.g.

```
public abstract class BasicCommand<TData> where TData : CommandData
{
    public TData Data { get; private set; }
    public ??? GameModel { get; private set; } 
    
    // parameter-less constructor required to fulfill the generics type constraint "new()"
    protected BasicCommand() { }

    // required to fill in the data when creating via parameter-less constructor
    public void Init(??? gameModel, TData data)
    {
        GameModel = gameModel;
        Data = data;
    }

    protected BasicCommand(??? gameModel, TData data)
    {
        GameModel = gameModel;
        Data = data;
    }

    public void RegisterOnComplete(??? onComplete)
    {
        ???
    }
}
```

and the implementations

```
public class StartGame : BasicCommand<StartGameData>
{
    public StartGame(??? gameModel, StartGameData data)
        : base(gameModel, data) { }
}

public class SetupGame : BasicCommand<SetupGameData>
{
    public SetupGame(??? gameModel, SetupGameData data)
        : base(gameModel, data) { }
}
```

so finally you could have a method like e.g.

```
public void CreateLocalCommand<TData, TCommand>(??? gameModel, string message) where TData : CommandData where TCommand : BasicCommand<TData>, new()
{
    var commandData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TData>(message);
    
    // intances created via generics can't have any parameters
    var command = new TCommand();
    // so initialize later
    command1.Init(gameModel, commandData);
    
    command.RegisterOnComplete(StartGame);
    gameModel.commandManager.AddCommand(command);
}
```

You would call this like e.g.

```
CreateLocalCommand<SetupCommandData, SetupCommand>(gameModel, message);
```

---

#### Reflection

Or the alternative would be the [`Activator`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.activator) (see [Reflection](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/reflection) in general).

```
public void CreateLocalCommand(Type dataType, Type commandType, ??? gameModel, string message)
{
    var commandData = (CommandData) JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(message, dataType);
    
    // This creates aninstance of type commandType
    // and passes "gameModel" and "commandData" as parameters to the constructor
    var command = (BasicCommand) Activator.CreateInstance(commandType, gameModel, commandData);
    
    command.RegisterOnComplete(StartGame);
    gameModel.commandManager.AddCommand(command);
}
```

You would call this like e.g.

```
CreateLocalCommand(typeof(SetupCommandData), typeof(SetupCommand), gameModel, message);
```

**In general I would try to avoid reflection as much as possible since here you don't have any compile time type checks!** You would rather need to add some runtime checks like e.g.

```
if(!dataType.IsSubclassOf(typeof(CommandData))
{
    throw new ArgumentException($"Given type {(dataType == null ? "null" : dataType.FullName)} is not a subclass of {typeof(CommandData).FullName}");
}
```

Comment: Generics would also have been my first idea. But in contrast to C++, you do not have "template specializationn" in C# (I think). And that makes it harder to come up with a good solution using generics in this case.

Comment: @BitTickler didn't I show a way to do it though? ;) There are [Type constraints](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters) which limit the possible generic type parameters .. by chaining them the way I showed it is possible to force a specific data type and command type together